# SVG content get cropped for dynamic values

Tags: css, svg, height, viewbox

I have an color legend for discrete data, which is done using SVG. But I am getting issue to display the whole content as it is getting cropped. I cannot define fixed height since content are dynamic.

FYI: My code is written in react

Note: I can give overflow: visible and make the content visible but again then the issue comes in giving background color (background color wont get apply for overflowed content).

Code link: https://jsfiddle.net/rb4p9max/4/

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  // calling legend function and passing div id to function
  colorLegend("#legend");
}, [dep]);

function colorLegend(legend: string) {
  // logic
  select(legend)
  .append("svg")
  .attr("height", 100 + "%")
  .attr("width", 100 + "%")
  .style("background-color", "black")
  .style("border-radius", "5px")
  .call(colorLegend);
}

return (
  <div style={{position: "absolute",right: 16,top: 10,backgroundColor: 
  "grey"}}>
    <div id="legend"></div>
  </div> 
);
```

Comment: Your SVG lacs a viewBox attribute like viewBox="0 0 80 175" where 175 = 7 * 25 because your legend has 7 items

Comment: @enxaneta I have both vertical and horizontal layout for legend and for vertical I have used "transform", "rotate(90deg)". How to calculate height and width for the vertical layout ?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand you. Please ask all this in a new question and do not forget to add an image with the desired result

Comment: I agree with you. I applied rapheal solution (height: calc(22px * ${legends.length} + (4px * ${legends.length -1}));) for my vertical layout of legend and it worked. But give issue for horizontal layout (I rotated it to 90deg). I need proper width and height for horizontal layout as well. Ex: https://jsfiddle.net/518enwam/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to answer it with just a small example from the react code. But, based on the fiddle you submitted, you could set a fixed height, but based on the number of legends you have. Something like:

```
height: calc(22px * 7 + (4px * 6));
```

Explaining the numbers:
22px * 7 is because every square is 22px height.
4px * 6 is accounting for the bottom margin. You don't need a bottom margin in the last one.

https://jsfiddle.net/gzebj1qn/

So, the final code would be something like:

```
height: calc(22px * ${legends.length} + (4px * ${legends.length -1}));
```

Comment: I cannot set fixed height because legends can vary, it need not be 7. It can be 10 or 3 as well. I had used overflow visible and made legend to display but then the background color is  not getting applied for overflowed content (Last legend)

Comment: That's why I put the code below using variables. :)

Comment: Again, I don't have the full react code. But your legends are coming from an array, or an object. Either way, you have what you need to create the height.

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked for me for horizontal layout. But I have both vertical and horizontal layout for legend and for vertical I have used "transform", "rotate(90deg)". What will be the height and width for the vertical layout ? Also giving width as 100% takes more width than required.

Comment: to be more clear, your suggestion works well for vertical layout of legend. But give issue for horizontal layout (I rotated it to 90deg). I need proper width and height for horizontal layout as well. Ex: https://jsfiddle.net/518enwam/3/